# How to make a view controller appear from the left and to not fill the full view?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, custom-controls

How to make a UiViewController appear from the right of the screen,  the same way as this  application(Break) does on iPad.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/funny-videos-pics-by-break.com/id342257973?mt=8

In fact, I would like that my UIViewController appears on the screen from a side and not to fill the entire UIView of my main ui view controller. The background view should also be darken.

To sum up, I would like to mimic the same Break's behavior.

Here is a picture if needed

[image]

Any idea ? Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to just do some manual work with UIViews. So rather than push a viewcontroller onto the stack you would overlay a semi transparent black view over your background view to darken it and then simply do an addSubView of the view you want to show on top.